# Exchange2013 only works with Phones, Webmail, and Windows 10 Mail Client, Everything BUT MS OUTLOOK

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

So we recently upgraded our on premises server exchange 2013 to the latest roll-up, I also think its important to note that, we use office 365 for various things (but not email obviously)

Mobile Phone Mail, Web Mail client (OWA) ALL WORK!? using the on premises exchange 2013 server so I know it works,
 Also The windows 10 built in mail client works!?

This is a serious mystery to me I have been working on it for days, the boss is NOT happy,  and every day that goes by I fear for my life (joke)

But seriously there must be a reason this is happening. Why does it work for everything EXCEPT MICROSOFT OUTLOOK?!

Why does it prompt us twice for passwords and it goes like this:
First time , it prompts us, we put in email and password, and it goes through no problem
Second prompt , (kind of looks like a Microsoft Account prompt to me) that does not go through 
and prevents us from accessing our email.

PLEASE HELP ME ASAP I WILL BE FOREVER GRATEFUL!

pulling hair out - thank you
tom

Comment: kort3x is on the money. This is most likely O365 priority in Autodiscover. You can disable this behavior via Group Policy for domain joined machines by using the Office ADMX templates or via GPP registry changes. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211279/outlook-2016-implementation-of-autodiscover.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an Autodiscover issue to me.

Have you checked your virtual directories, dns, certificates, etc?

Comment: also: If you have added your domain to O365 be aware that newer Outlooks prioritize O365. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3211279/outlook-2016-implementation-of-autodiscover

Comment: Have you cheked what method Outlook is using for Autodiscover? See here under "More information": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/domain-management/unexpected-autodiscover-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue happen to all users? what errors you got when it prevents from accessing mails?

Run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365) to test Autodiscover, there are more details for your reference.

Have you tried to create outlook profiles for these users?

You could run outlook in safe mode to check if this issue continues.